# PhpStorm wrong background

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

After the update of PhpStorm, in Blade templates, the `script` tag is highlighted:

[image]

in the settings, all is ok:

[image]

Why this is highlighted?

Comment: If you just hover over the area that is highlighted, does it tell you anything?

Comment: I updated the question. I see on the first picture, that `cost_center_name` is underlined and i get the remark "unsolved variable". But it's part of webix...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in Language Injection for NOT "Built-in" rows, disable item that you not recognize.

[image: phpstorm language injection]