# PhpStorm syntax highlighting doesn't work within <div> tags

Tags: php, phpstorm, syntax-highlighting

I'm facing a curious PhpStorm syntax highlighter behavior:

In a .php file when an html comment `<!-- xxx -->` or php marker `<? echo "xxx" ?>` is embedded in a `div` marker, if it is not immediately followed (on the same line) by an other html tag, the syntax highlighter doesn't parse it correctly. Looks like it is not the case with other html tags like `<header>`

[image]

What does the green areas after `<div>` mean?

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Check if my similar answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59581588/phpstorm-wrong-background/59582194#59582194

Comment: You must have accidentally created custom Language Injection rule that injects some language inside all `<div>` tags. Such injection will force that language there and your PHP code will be treated as plain text/as that language (depends on what has been injected ... most likely it's HTML). Just delete such wrong rule (see comment above with the link)

Comment: Thank you for your remarks, I had accidentally create a custom Language Injection rule.