# Unreadable PhpStorm coverage colors

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

After running PHPUnit with coverage, PhpStorm applies a weird theme on all the lines of the code:

[image]

This is absolutely unreadable. Anyone knows how to disable these?  Is it a known issue (I couldn't find a bug report)?

I tried to modify the line coverage color scheme, but it does not change it.

I have this issue on all PHP projects but one...

Comment: If anyone is having the same issue, adding a line and removing it will remove the highlighting

Comment: Check if my similar answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59581588/phpstorm-wrong-background/59582194#59582194

Comment: Do you have [PHPUnit code coverage](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6167-phpunit-code-coverage) plugin installed?

Looks similar to https://github.com/oker1/phpunit_codecoverage_display/issues/18

Comment: @r_a_f It's not the case here as Language Injection cannot be injected in such places. It's either a 3rd party plugin issue (as mentioned by lena; that plugin is not really needed as IDE can show coverage without it just fine) or theme colors misconfiguration.

Comment: @Entilore 1) If you have that plugin -- please disable it and restart IDE. By default IDE should be showing coverage colors in gutter area only (the area on the left side where line numbers and those (O) icons are as per your screenshot)

Comment: @Entilore If you want to have the actual line background in Editor colored (instead of/in addition to default gutter) then configure appropriate styles in `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Line Coverage` -- use custom Background color for "Full" and "Uncovered" entries.

Comment: Thanks @lena, that was this plugin indeed. I don't remember  installing this plugin, which is absolutely useless. The gutter area is all I need.

Comment: Thanks also @LazyOne, I only need the gutter :)